# How to not write spaghetti-code/huge activities w/Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to avoid having gigantic activity classes that are hard to follow, but the platform seems to be making it hard. Doing almost anything requires a activity or context - these can be stored away in a helper class, but unfortunately calls like startActivityForResult, for example, don't take a sperate listener but always call back on the same activity on an override with a supplied integer code - so this means that seperation of concerns is hard - the main activity needs to know about the helper class and dispactch to the helper class based on an request code - and of course, that request code needs to be unique, so that's a leaky abstraction as well. Why not specify a listener for every call thus avoiding the dispatching and need for unique request codes? Any other ways to slice this?
thanks

Comment: I think Fragments will address this a little in HoneyComb, but I haven't used them yet, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I'd advise against storing the context in the helper class...IMO you're better off passing the context as a parameter to each helper function that needs it. Minimizing the state that each class keeps improves thread safety and reusability.

Comment: I think you should concentrate on Splitting your UI code (Activity) from your Processing (Helpers)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Yes, storing state that may be invalid if an activity is popped isn't a great solution. However, the idea was for other code in the activity to not need to be tightly coupled to the code in the helper - using the response code means that a switch statement in the activity must know about all helpers I've instantiated, and have a unique int assigned. Yes, I figured that marshalling to other objects other than the activity would incur some cost, but in the scheme of things not too much - but I could be wrong here.

Comment: >I think you should concentrate on Splitting your UI code (Activity) from your Processing (Helpers) 
Yes - that's what I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 2):

In API level 11 and higher, you can use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

Comment: Fragments have been back ported to 1.6. See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a listener would be difficult since it would require passing an object to other processes in the Android environment- remember that activities can be called from one application to another.

How is using request codes making your activities "huge" in a way that listeners wouldn't? Activities should make use of classes defined elsewhere to do more most of the labor, let your activities pertain primarily to UI tasks.

Comment: Re: huge (perhaps overstatement) -- because with seperate listeners after initalization, I wouldn't have to have all my logic in the activity (or at least dispatched from there)